# Accessing pointer member variable of the innermost of three nested structs

Tags: c

```
typedef struct {

   struct {
      double i1, i2;
   } EXP;

   struct {
      double i1, i2;
   } SIN;

   struct {
      double i1, i2;
   } PULSE;

   struct {
      double *i1, *i2;
   } PWL;
} TRANS;

struct term {
   TRANS trans;
   struct term *nxt;
};

int main() {
   struct term *look;
}
```

I have the above structs and the pointer look to the struct term. Could someone tell me how  to dereference pointer i1 inside struct PWL?

I've tried this:

```
*(look->trans.PWL.i1)
```

but it produces segmentation fault.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to allocate memory for your objects.

Comment: `struct term *look = malloc(sizeof(*look));`

Comment: Actually struct term is a list, i have allocated some nodes and i'm trying to print them. struct term *look is pointer which i use to traverse the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segmentation fault is because you allocated a pointer, but did not create memory for the pointer to point at. Once you do that, then `*(look->trans.PWL.i1)` is indeed how to access that field in the inner struct.

You need to allocate memory for the struct, and all references within.

```
struct term *look = malloc(sizeof(struct term));
look->trans.PWL.i1 = malloc(sizeof(double));
look->trans.PWL.i2 = malloc(sizeof(double));
```

And naturally you need to reverse the process with calls to `free` when you are done.

```
free(look->trans.PWL.i2);
free(look->trans.PWL.i1);
free(look);
```

Or, perhaps `i1` and `i2` are meant to point to values that are allocated elsewhere then it would look like this:

```
struct term *look = malloc(sizeof(struct term));
look->trans.PWL.i1 = &look->trans.EXP.i1;
look->trans.PWL.i2 = &look->trans.EXP.i2;
```

And to deallocate you just free `look`. Remember to pair each successful call to `malloc` with a call to `free`.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to `PWL.i1`

```
int main() {
   struct term *look;                   // set up your variable
   look = malloc(sizeof(struct term));  // give it some memory
   look->trans.PWL.i1 = malloc(sizeof(double)); //give some memory to your double pointer
   *(look->trans.PWL.i1) = 5.0;         // assign it a value
   printf("%lf\n", *(look->trans.PWL.i1));
   return 0;
}
```

So since `look` is a pointer to a `term` structure, that means when you access it's elements you need to deference it then access the members (`->`) once you have that you just access the other members via the `.` operator:

```
look->trans.PWL.i1
```

In this case PWL's `i1` member is a pointer so you have to deference the whole thing to assign a value. (before doing so, again you need to allocate some memory there)

And free everything when you're done of course.